# Why tensor product of two sheaves of modules is a sheaf of modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ be  a ringed topological space. Consider two $\mathcal O_X$ modules, $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$. First we define the tensor product presheaf $\mathcal F \otimes_{p,\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$, which assigns every open set $U$ in $X$ the $\mathcal O_X(U)$-module $\mathcal F(U) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X(U)} \mathcal G(U)$. Now, $\mathcal F \otimes_{p,\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$ is a presheaf of **abelian groups**. We take the the sheafication of the $\mathcal F \otimes_{p,\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$ to obtain a **sheaf of abelian groups**, $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$. My question is for any open set $U$ in $X$ what is the $\mathcal O_X(U)$-module on   $(\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(U)$?

Answer (score 22):

If $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ is a scheme and if $U\subset X$ is is an open **affine** subscheme, then  we have for all **quasi-coherent** sheaves $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$ of $\mathcal O_X$-modules the extremely pleasant  equality of $\mathcal O_X(U)$-modules:

> $$(\mathcal F \otimes_{ \mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(U)=      \mathcal F(U) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X(U)} \mathcal G(U)         $$

However if $U$ is not affine all hell can break loose:
For example if $X=\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$ is the complex projective line and if $\mathcal F=\mathcal O_X(1), \mathcal G=\mathcal O_X(-1)$, then for these quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathcal F \otimes_{ \mathcal O_X} \mathcal G=\mathcal O_X$, so that for  $U=X$: 
$$(\mathcal F \otimes_{ \mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(X)=  \mathcal O_X(X) =\mathbb C \neq  \mathcal F(X)\otimes _{\mathcal O_X(X)}\mathcal G(X)=\mathbb C^2\otimes_\mathbb  C  0=0$$

**Reference**
The first displayed equality is proved in [Qing-Liu](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~qliu/Book/index.html), chapter 5, Proposition 1.12 (b), page 162.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Just to double check, $\mathcal F(X)$ is the space of quotients of homogenous polynomials in two variables, with the top one degree more than the bottom, and the bottom shouldn't vanish on $\mathbb P^1$. So the bottom ends up being a nonzero constant (by projective Nullstellensatz), and the top is just a degree 1 homogenous polynomial, which can be identified with $\mathbb C^2$ as you said.

Comment: Dear hwong, your comment is perfectly correct. More genrally the set of global sections $\mathcal O_{\mathbb  P^n}(d)(\mathbb  P^n)$  of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb  P^n}(d)$ consists  of the polynomials in $n+1$ indeterminates which are homogeneous of degree $d$. (In particular if $d\lt 0$ the only global section is zero!) The dimension of that vector space of sections  $\mathcal O_{\mathbb  P^n}(d)(\mathbb  P^n)$ is $\binom {n+d}{d}$, which is indeed equal to $2$ for $n=d=1$

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking for the $\mathcal O_X(U)$ action on $(\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(U)$? If so, it works on the level of stalks. Let $f \in \mathcal O_X(U)$ and let $s \in (\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(U)$. $s$ can be thought of as a collection of compatible germs $s_p \in \mathcal F_p \otimes_{\mathcal O_{x, p}} \mathcal G_p$. Then $f \cdot s$ is the collection of germs $f_p \cdot s_p$, where the dot is the $\mathcal O_{x, p}$-module action on $\mathcal F_p \otimes_{\mathcal O_{x, p}} \mathcal G_p$. One just needs to verify that the collection of $f_ps_p$ is still a collection of compatible germs, which they are.

Comment: Yes. I actually just want to prove $(\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)(U)$ is a $\mathcal O_X(U)$. Is there any way to see that without going to the level of stalks?

Comment: Dear grok: given any presheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, its sheafification is automatically an $\mathcal O_X$-module too. Apply this to the presheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $\mathcal F \otimes_{p,\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$ whose sheafification is $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$

Comment: @grok. I agree with Georges' comment above, but as far as I know, the only way to see that $(\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G)$ is an $\mathcal O_X(U)$-module is to go through stalks. The sheafification is in terms of stalks so I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: @hwong557 You can use the (universal) properties of the sheafification functor to establish the $\mathcal O_X$-module without reference to stalks. One way to do this is to define a multiplication map for any open $U\subset X$ and any $\sigma\in\mathcal O_X(U)$, and then check well-definedness (which is easy).