# Understanding line bundles on $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ using transition functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, line-bundles

Vakil defines $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^1}(n)$ as follows: it is Spec $k[x_1/x_0]$ on $U_0 = D(x_0)$, and Spec $k[x_0/x_1]$ on $U_1 = D(x_1)$, and the transition function from $U_0$ to $U_1$ is multiplication by $(x_0/x_1)^n$.Then he claims that from this definition it's obvious that $\mathcal{O}(n) = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes n}$.

1. I'm not sure if I completely understand transition functions. Is it basically giving a glue along the open sets $D(x_0/x_1) \subset U_0$ and $D(x_1/x_0) \subset U_1$?
2. I don't see how $\mathcal{O}(n) = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes n}$ follows easily from this transition function definition. Tensor product of sheaves is pretty mysterious to me because you have to sheafify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 2, you can use that, if $F$ and $G$ are quasi-coherent sheaves, and $U$ is an affine open, then $(F \otimes G)(U) = F(U) \otimes G(U)$, where the latter tensor product is over $\mathscr{O}(U)$. This is also true of morphisms between quasi-coherent sheaves. This will let you compute the tensor product, and conclude the 'obvious' fact. (It's not obvious.)

See here for a reference: [Why tensor product of two sheaves of modules is a sheaf of modules?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974593/why-tensor-product-of-two-sheaves-of-modules-is-a-sheaf-of-modules)

It's also in Ravi, around where he introduces QCoh, I think.

Comment: That's a good point! I think the fact is kind of obvious then (correct me if I'm wrong) - for example, let $\mathscr{F} = \mathcal{O}(1) \otimes \mathcal{O}(1)$, and let $f (x_0/x_1) \otimes g(x_0/x_1) \in \mathscr{F}(U_0 \cap U_1)$, then the transition function will map this to $f(1/(x_1/x_0)) \cdot (x_1/x_0) \otimes g(1/(x_1/x_0)) \cdot (x_1/x_0) = (x_1/x_0)^2(f(1/(x_1/x_0)) \otimes g(1/(x_1/x_0)))$, which is exactly the transition function for $\mathcal{O}(2)$.

Comment: @AaronJohnson That looks right to me! (About obviousness -- lot's of things in math are obvious in retrospect, since you get used to certain hammers like the fact I mentioned, but not when you are learning them. I just generally feel irked when teachers / relative experts use that language in front of their students.)

Comment: Totally agreed, "obvious" can be a very irritating word.