# Tensor Product of $\mathcal O_X$-Modules is not a Sheaf, trouble understanding example

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am looking for an example where the tensor product presheaf of two $\mathcal O_X$-modules is not a sheaf.  I have seen the example with [Serre's twisting sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1974676/540354), but this requires some tedious work to show the property $\mathcal O_X (-1) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_X(1) = \mathcal O_X(0)$.  The following example I am working with is a little more simple.

> - $X = \operatorname{Spec}k[x]$, $k$ some (maybe algebraically closed) field
> - $\mathcal F (U) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } (x) \in U \\ \mathcal O_X(U) & \text{if } (x) \notin U\end{cases}$
> - $\mathcal G (U) = \begin{cases} k & \text{if } (x-1) \in U \\ 0 & \text{if } (x-1) \notin U\end{cases}$
>
> We have $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G = \mathcal G$,
>   but $\mathcal F(X) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X(X)} \mathcal G(X) = 0 \neq k = \mathcal G(X)$, hence $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X}^{\mathrm{pre}} \mathcal G \neq \mathcal G = \mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G$, which means that
>   $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X}^{\mathrm{pre}} \mathcal G$ is not a
>   sheaf.

What I am having trouble with, is to show that $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G = \mathcal G$.  I have tried showing that $\mathcal G$ is the tensor product of $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ by showing that it fulfills the universal property of the tensor product of $\mathcal O_X$-modules, but I struggle to see what happens when $(x-1) \in U$ and $(x) \in U$ (big commuting diagrams that led nowhere, or at least seemingly).  I also have considered finding a morphism $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G \to \mathcal G$ and showing that it is an isomorphism on the stalks.  What is the easiest way to see $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal G = \mathcal G$?

Comment: The second method is the easiest way. There is an obvious $\mathcal{F}(U)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X(U)}\mathcal{G}(U)\to \mathcal{G}(U)$. Explicitely, if $(x)\in U$, this map is zero (since $\mathcal{F}(U)=0$), and if $(x)\not\in U$, this map is $\mathcal{O}_X(U)_{\mathcal{O}_X(U)}\mathcal{G}(U)\simeq\mathcal{G}(U)$ the obvious isomorphism. This is a map of presheaves $\mathcal{F}\otimes^{pre}_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{G}$. Now this is an isomorphism on stalks : if $p\neq (x-1)$ then both side are zero, and if $p=(x-1)$, then both side is $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually solved this exercise today, with your outline.  I might post a detailed answer myself...

Comment: Hi @Berber, did you post it?

Comment: @Framate  I am so sorry that I haven't done this.  This was a homework a longer time ago, and I was lazy to post my solution (I do remember there were details that I wanted to stress and that I wanted to explain stuff extensively), but I was too lazy.  It would be a good exercise to do this again.  Sadly I don't have the time to do this now, I would have to take time to review this algebraic geometry stuff.